# Java: объясните поведение компилятора

Tags: ооп, компилятор, java, компиляция

Здравствуйте! Столкнулся со странным поведением компилятора, объясните пожалуйста, почему происходит вывод разных строк.

```
class EntityModel{
    public String name;
    public EntityModel(){
        this.name = "EntityModel";
    }
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
}
class Model1 extends EntityModel{
    public String name;
    public Model1(){
        this.name = "Model1";
    }

    @Override
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Вызов:

```
EntityModel m = (EntityModel)new Model1();  
System.out.println(m.name);
System.out.println(m.getName());
```

Вывод:

```
EntityModel
Model1
```

Код на [`ideone.com`](http://ideone.com/J5fs4P)

Почему обращение к полю на прямую и через геттер дают разные результаты?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Хе :)

Если коротко, то в Java методы виртуальные, а *поля* — нет. То есть, привязка метода к имени метода производится на этапе выполнения в соответствии с настоящим, динамическим типом объекта, а вот привязка поля — статическая, производится на этапе компиляции.

Так сделано потому, что выставлять наружу открытое поле всё равно очень плохая практика, поэтому доступ к полям можно ускорить за счёт точного определения поля во время компиляции. А вот вызывая публичный метод, программист не ожидает вызова не самого «свежего» метода, так что здесь логичнее виртуальный вызов. (Впрочем, архитекторы C# считают не так, но это уже вопрос дизайна языков.)

Это всё ещё один аргумент к тому, чтобы делать все поля private, и получать доступ к ним лишь через getter.

Comment: Компилятор C# выдаст предупреждение о сокрытии имени, которое убирается явным указанием `new` у поля.

Comment: @AlexeyM: Дело в том, что в C# методы по умолчанию _не_ виртуальные, в отличие от Java.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что в первом случае считывается поле EntityModel.name, а во втором случае обращение к методу EntityModel.getName() приводит к вызову Model1.getName(), поскольку второй метод переопределяет первый. Так работает обращение к полям и методам, и об этом написано в любом учебнике.

Comment: Но у Model1 есть тоже поле name, почему к нему не обращается?

Comment: потому что обращение к полю транслируется в простое считывание ячейки памяти по адресу m+(сдвиг поля). Вы что хотите, чтобы сдвиг пересчитывался каждый раз при обращении к полю? Ведь в переменной m могут быть и ссылки на чистые EntityModel, где никаких других name нету. Вычисление адреса метода транслируется в m.getClass().vmt+(сдвиг метода), а сдвиг метода getName опять же один и тот же для всех классов - наследников EntityModel, включая сам EntityModel. То есть, все сделано для получения эффективного кода.